# Parser error on simplexml_load_file()

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to parse an xml document using php simplexml_load_file() function.

I have a demo.xml file in the site root

**demo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<sms>
<sender>foo bar</sender>
 <sentto>john doe</sentto>
 </sms>
```

And I am trying to get the value of **sender** , the following is my php code :

```
<?php

$xml=simplexml_load_file("demo.xml");
echo $xml->sender;
```

But I am getting the parser error whenever i try to load the php file.

```
Parser error : blank needed here in www/htdocs/read.php on line 3.
```

How can I solve it?

Thanks ,SK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here

```
<?xml version="1.0"encoding="UTF-8" ?>
------------------^
```

A space is needed, change it to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, with your xml ,now I am getting this error : 

**Xml declaration allowed only at the start of the document on line 3** ,Do you know what it means and how to get rid of it?

Comment: maybe the contents of your `demo.xml` start with some newline?